# ChromeDriver starts the Chrome.app but does not drive anything. I am getting: Could not start a new session

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium

So this is the code I have:

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.hepsiburada.com");
```

When I run this code, Chrome actually starts however after a while I get:

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not
>   start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote
>   server or browser start-up failure. Build info: version: '2.47.2',
>   revision: '4d972c01cab1304452627f837654326a11eb92fe', time:
>   '2015-09-24 09:17:17' System info: host: 'Korays-MacBook-Pro.local',
>   ip: '192.168.2.137', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64',
>   os.version: '10.10.5', java.version: '1.7.0_79'

any help?

Answer (score 0):

You have to download Download the [chromedriver binary](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) for your platform  and you have to mention that in the `System.setProperty` .
What you have referred is the location where chrome installed which is wrong.

As per [ChromeDriver](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/getting-started) the following is the correct approach

```
 // Optional, if not specified, WebDriver will search your path for chromedriver.
  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/path/to/chromedriver");

  WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```